# Accessing a database which is out of project

Tags: spring, jpa

I must have spring in a project.
I have an internal db that is generated by local entities with entity annotations.
But also i must access a second, out of project database with jpa, entityManager.
How can i configure persistence.xml and annotations.
Project already have openjpa to access local database.
I want to know,

1. should i put @Entity for outer database entities?
2. should i put table for outer database entities?
3. how can i prevent openJPA or spring to trying to generate tables
   again?
4. also my external database was generated by an outer project with,
   spring, jpa. And its tables have name like MYPROJECT_address,
   MYPROJECT_message.How can i tell my access_out_project that there
   are    built tables there with these entities.

So far i wrote into persistence.xml of access_out_project for outer access to outer db:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>pack.EmailAddress</class>
        <class>pack.Message</class>
           <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kepsDb" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            </properties>

        </persistence-unit>
```

But it tries to generate tables with a name like message, address. I
    do not know how to prevent it to generate them again.

But the main questions are above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

This will tell hibernate to only validate that tables exist.